# SBS 2008 coexist with Server Standard for Remote Desktop Services

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-sbs

I need to provide secure remote desktop access to multiple users in a small business.  I believe they currently are running SBS 2008 (identifies as Windows Server Standard FE).  My understanding is that Remote Desktop Services cannot be installed on an SBS server.  My questions--can I add another Windows Standard Server to the domain and run Remote Desktop Services on it?  Anything I should be careful about or consider in advance with this scenario?

Hardware for the 2nd server is available and licensing is affordable as they are a non-profit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set up a second server in an SBS 2008 domain and run terminal services on that.  [This is the preferred solution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd262139%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).  In fact, SBS 2008 Premium comes with the second server's license already (you might want to check and see if they already have that second license).